# Flutter dio image upload not working throws server 401 error, but works in postman

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, dio

This is my postman request with a header Authorization Bearer Token.

I am trying to upload the image, everything is set up as mentioned with the documents dio and exactly the same as the postman parameter, but it is throwing a 401 error, it is giving me an Unauthorized error, it would appear that it is not taking the token to process and upload the file. I was reading and moving options that were mentioned in post, but unfortunately I have not been successful.
I would be very grateful if someone could give me some guidance and help me to get the process done.

[image: postman]

My dio request:

```
employeeAttachFile(File file) async {

  final SecureStorage _secureStorage = SecureStorage();
  final token = await _secureStorage.readToken('token');

  final String uri = '${ApiPaths.basisApi}${ApiPaths.addEmployeesFile}15';

  String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
  print(fileName);

  FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      file.path,
      filename: fileName,
    ),
  });

  Dio dio = new Dio(BaseOptions(
      headers: {"Authorization": token}, contentType: "application/json"));
  await dio.post(uri, data: data).then((response) {
    var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
  }).catchError((error) => print(error));
}
```

This is my error:

[image: Error]

Comment: and you are sure that your `request` do really contain that valid `Authorization` header (see last image you posted)?

Comment: Yes, the header must have this authorization in order to be able to make the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`{'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'}`

Comment: Funciono, pero al realizar el envío del archivo me regresa un error 400. Pareciera que el archivo que estoy enviando es inválido o el peso es muy grande.  Lo mandé desde Postman con el mismo archivo y lo cargo sin problemas. `Response ({"statusCode":400,"message":"The file doesn't have a valid format or size","error":"Bad Request"})`

Comment: You can debug line by line and see what exact headers are being sent. It could be that the server did not like some other header.